# C programming: Redirect the output of an encryption program into a .txt file

Tags: shell

I have written an encryption program in c but how can i redirect the output in a **.txt** file .I didn't use file processing in this encryption program. I have tried with redirection operator(./encrypt>txt.txt). I am using gcc compiler.Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: in what way did using the redirection operator not work?

Comment: You need to provide a [MCVE]. Does your program write to `stdout`?

Comment: No source, no help

Comment: encrypt>txt.txt this looks like cmd line option, not std c. Write it into a file with fopen and fprintf

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: This is not related to C programming. You ask for a shell feature. Please don't add irrelevant tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are writing your output to `stdout` using `fwrite()` or `printf()` (and friends), you can use `freopen()` to 'reopen' a file handle.

The following example will 'reopen' `stdout`:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *f;

    f = freopen("./output.txt", "w", stdout);
    if (f == NULL) {
        perror("freopen()");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Hello World!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Here, the `Hello World!` will be written to `./output.txt`.

If you comment out the call to `freopen()`, then `Hello World!` will appear on the console.

---

If you are not using `fwrite()` or `printf()` (but rather the lower-level `write()` family that operate on 'file descriptors'), then you will need to use `dup2()` - happy to provide an example.